# What's peculiar about F21-F24 keys on MacOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I observed some questions on the Internet concerning this.

- [F20-F24 keys do not respond, but are mapped](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192066/f20-f24-keys-do-not-respond-but-are-mapped)
- https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/f-keys-f13-to-f24/8953
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1090226

Karabiner-Elements can map from F1~F24, but can only map to F1~F20

And you can tell the OS is aware of there keys from this reply: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/f-keys-f13-to-f24/8953/7

So what's peculiar about F21~F24 on MacOS?

Comment: Which actual problem are you trying to solve here? Are you looking for ways to use a keyboard with F21-F24?

Answer (score 2):

If [this post](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/1918#issuecomment-430602936) at the Hammerspoon GitHub site is right:

[image]

then macOS does not handle F21~F24 (0x70~0x73) at all.

And it makes sense for Karabiner to not deliver any of these keys to the OS because of that.

Comment: That’s not correct.  The OS receives scan codes.  Whether macOS does anything with them is irrelevant. If it’s received, you can work  with it.  You need to see if the OS is receiving the scan code.  See this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317556/119271

Answer (score 2):

It tested it on my Macro-Pad with QMK firmware.
Assigned F21, F22, F23 and F24 to some keys.

MAC OSX (10.15.7) receives it (tested with Karabiner EventViewer) and you can assign it in Karabiner.

[image]

Comment: Karabiner can detect them, and that's what I was saying. Try with another app like Emacs. I doubt it can detect them.